# Setting the default starting date to null in jquery mobile datebox

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I do not want to highlight the present date in my jquery mobile datebox.Setting `calHighToday` to `false` in options helps me to do this.But the problem is by default the present date is selected when the application is loaded.I can use `defaultDate` to start with a particular date selected.But how to avoid the highlighting of any date when it is loaded.Setting `defaultDate` to null did not seem to do the trick.

Check out a sample here - http://jsfiddle.net/na6Be/1/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/na6Be/5/

JS:

```
$('div.ui-btn-up-e').removeClass('ui-btn-up-e').addClass('ui-btn-up-a').attr('data-theme','a');
```

Note:

This might change if you're using a different theme